# How to parse top level XML element php

Tags: php, xml, laravel, webhooks

I have an XML response that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<new_subscription_notification>
  <account>
    <account_code>1</account_code>
    <username nil="true">verena</username>
    <email>verena@example.com</email>
    <first_name>Verena</first_name>
    <last_name>Example</last_name>
    <company_name nil="true">Company, Inc.</company_name>
  </account>
  <subscription>
    <plan>
      <plan_code>bronze</plan_code>
      <name>Bronze Plan</name>
    </plan>
    <uuid>8047cb4fd5f874b14d713d785436ebd3</uuid>
    <state>active</state>
    <quantity type="integer">2</quantity>
    <total_amount_in_cents type="integer">17000</total_amount_in_cents>
    <subscription_add_ons type="array">
      <subscription_add_on>
        <add_on_code>premium_support</add_on_code>
        <name>Premium Support</name>
        <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
        <unit_amount_in_cents type="integer">15000</unit_amount_in_cents>
        <external_sku>pre-123<external_sku>
        <add_on_type>fixed</add_on_type>
        <usage_percentage nil="true"></usage_percentage>
        <measured_unit_id nil="true"></measured_unit_id>
      </subscription_add_on>
      <subscription_add_on>
        <add_on_code>email_blasts</add_on_code>
        <name>Email Blasts</name>
        <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
        <external_sku>email-123<external_sku>
        <unit_amount_in_cents type="integer">50</unit_amount_in_cents>
        <add_on_type>usage</add_on_type>
        <usage_percentage nil="true"></usage_percentage>
        <measured_unit_id type="integer">394681687402874853</measured_unit_id>
      </subscription_add_on>
      <subscription_add_on>
        <add_on_code>donations</add_on_code>
        <name>Donations</name>
        <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
        <unit_amount_in_cents nil="true"></unit_amount_in_cents>
        <add_on_type>usage</add_on_type>
        <usage_percentage>0.6</usage_percentage>
        <measured_unit_id type="integer">394681920153192422</measured_unit_id>
      </subscription_add_on>
    </subscription_add_ons>
    <activated_at type="datetime">2009-11-22T13:10:38Z</activated_at>
    <canceled_at type="datetime"></canceled_at>
    <expires_at type="datetime"></expires_at>
    <current_period_started_at type="datetime">2009-11-22T13:10:38Z</current_period_started_at>
    <current_period_ends_at type="datetime">2009-11-29T13:10:38Z</current_period_ends_at>
    <trial_started_at type="datetime">2009-11-22T13:10:38Z</trial_started_at>
    <trial_ends_at type="datetime">2009-11-29T13:10:38Z</trial_ends_at>
    <collection_method>automatic</collection_method>
  </subscription>
</new_subscription_notification>
```

I am converting it to a useable array with this:

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($request);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

It works super and gives me this array:

```
{"account":{"account_code":"shopify-3207741833301","username":{"@attributes":{"nil":"true"}},"email":"mum.matt@gmail.com","first_name":"Chrysanthemum","last_name":"Hayes","company_name":{"@attributes":{"nil":"true"}},"phone":{"@attributes":{"nil":"true"}}},"invoice":{"uuid":"53f16d5e15f0e9043a2c7c480d89af86","state":"paid","origin":"purchase","invoice_number_prefix":[],"invoice_number":"2567","address":{"address1":"3646 Deedham Drive","address2":[],"city":"San Jose","state":"CA","zip":"95148","country":"US","phone":[]},"vat_number":{"@attributes":{"nil":"true"}},"currency":"USD","balance_in_cents":"0","total_in_cents":"3389","tax_in_cents":"0","subtotal_in_cents":"3389","subtotal_before_discount_in_cents":"3389","discount_in_cents":"0","subscription_ids":{"@attributes":{"type":"array"}},"customer_notes":[],"created_at":"2020-06-05T03:59:23Z","updated_at":"2020-06-05T03:59:23Z","closed_at":"2020-06-05T03:59:23Z","shipping_address":{"name":"Angela Swartz","address1":"1324 Rainbow Dr","address2":[],"city":"San Mateo","state":"CA","zip":"94402","country":"US","phone":[]},"po_number":{"@attributes":{"nil":"true"}},"terms_and_conditions":[],"due_on":"2020-06-05T03:59:23Z","net_terms":"0","collection_method":"automatic"}}
```

The problem is that this webhook sends several different types of responses (It sends all responses to all webhooks addresses, I can't subscribe to just the one I want) and I only want to do work on responses with the `<new_subscription_notification>` top level XML element. When I do all my conversion to array, that element is not in the array, since it is essentially just the  element, but in this case, it has useful data.

Is there a way I can access that top level XML tag so that my code only runs when it gets the `<new_subscription_notification>` response?

Comment: As `$xml` is effectively the document AND the root node.  Using `echo $xml->getName();` will show you the element name of the root node.

Comment: @Nigel You are the real MVP and I am so grateful to you. Can I mark a comment as an answer?